# Azure SQL Database plan forcing

Tags: execution-plan, azure-sql-database

we've got Azure SQL Database with Automatic tuning - force plan turned on
sometimes executions continue with both the more expensive plan as well as the cheaper forced plan even though plan forcing is running (first picture) and sometimes the forced plan takes over completely (second picture).
Can anyone explain what might be causing the first pattern & how to get more information ?
Obviously the 2nd instance is working much better.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Adding a comment to keep the question fresh. Maybe worth mentioning these are fully parameterised queries. db compat is 130

Comment: update 2 - both queries are against the same single table, I was wondering if an automatic statistics update was responsible for a recompilation and a changed execution plan then subsequently being re-forced in example 1, but nothing in the last_force_failure_reason column in sys.query_store_plan, possibly my hypothesis is true and auto update stats is responsible - maybe stats update is one 1 column not used in example 2 - guessing I may need an extended events session.